# Upgrade to Enterprise Library 6.0 giving issues with 'EnterpriseLibraryContainer'

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

After upgrading to Enterprise Library 6.0 I'm having the following problem:

private static IUnityContainer container = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance();

> Cannot resolve EnterpriseLibraryContainer

I found another post that speaks about the EnterpriseLibraryCOntainer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323252/cannot-resolve-symbol-enterpriselibrarycontainer)

In the upgrade notes of Enterprise Library it states:

> “The name ‘EnterpriseLibraryContainer’ does not exist in the current context
>
> The bootstrapping code for all of the blocks has changed in version 6
>   of Enterprise Library. The blocks no longer use Unity to manage the
>   initialization and configuration, and each block now includes its own
>   bootstrapping code. Any calls to the
>   EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance method to resolve a
>   type from one of the Enterprise Library blocks should be replaced with
>   the block specific bootstrap code. For example, to create a LogWriter
>   instance based on configuration in the app.config file, you can now
>   use the following code: LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new
>   LogWriterFactory(); var logWriter = logWriterFactory.Create();

But I don't know how to handle this in the case of IUnityContainer. 
Could I just use

> IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using Unity now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical approach would be to bootstrap the block, register the appropriate objects with Unity and have Unity inject the dependencies.

For example, if you are using logging then you would bootstrap the block:

```
LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(); 
LogWriter logWriter = logWriterFactory.Create();
```

and register the LogWriter with the UnityContainer:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
// Register LogWriter as singleton
container.RegisterInstance<LogWriter>(logWriter);
```

If you were using the EnterpriseLibraryContainer as a service locator and wish to keep using that same approach then you could create/wrap a service locator implementation or create a static helper method.  Unity comes with UnityServiceLocator which you could reuse.

If you aren't using Unity, another approach would be to bootstrap the blocks and then replace the calls to `EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<>()` with the static facade methods (e.g. `Logger.Write()`).

Answer (score 1):

I've really struggled with this so here is my working upgrade from Enterprise 5 to v6 (fluent). I mention that in the Codeplex Migration PDF it still shows EnterpriseLibraryContainer, which is no longer valid.

// app.config

```
<configSections>
       <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
```

// my logger class
 using System;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;

```
/// <summary>
/// Set up the Enterprise logging class
/// </summary>
public static class Logging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Define the logging parameters
    /// </summary>
    public static void DefineLogger()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

        string loggerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        builder.ConfigureLogging()
               .WithOptions
                 .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
               .LogToCategoryNamed("LogWriter")
               .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
                 .SendTo.RollingFile("Rolling Flat File Trace Listener")
                 .RollAfterSize(1000)
                   .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
                     .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
                       .UsingTemplate(@"Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}Message: {message},{newline}Category: {category},{newline}Severity: {severity},{newline}Title:{title},{newline}ProcessId: {localProcessId},{newline}Process Name: {localProcessName},{newline}Thread Name: {threadName}"))
                       .ToFile(loggerPath + Properties.Settings.Default.LogFileFolder);

        // Reference app.config
        using (DictionaryConfigurationSource configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource())
        {
            builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);

            Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory(configSource).Create());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in any old exception:

```
Logger.Write("This is my log");
```

I hope this helps save alot of time.