# EnterpriseLibrary.current.GetInstance for ValidatorFactory class with upgraded nuget package (6.0.1304)

Tags: c#, nuget-package, enterprise-library, .net-4.6.1

I am facing an issue with EnterpriseLibrary.current.GetInstance for ValidatorFactory class. I am upgrading nuget package to 6.0.1304. please suggest similary methods to implement using nuget Enterprise Library 6.0 and ValidatorFactory

Code developed in enterpriselibrary 5.0.5

```
ValidtorFactory vald = EnterpriselibraryContainer.current.getInstance<ValidotorFactory>();
Validator validtor= vald.creatvalidator<T>(this.Gettype);
```

First line gives above error as follows
EnterpriselibraryContainer does not exists

Comment: So what is the issue? Are you seeing an error? Is there an exception stack? Where does it break? What call?

Comment: Added code. Plz help

Comment: You should include not only code, but the actual error as well. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post the entire error message, including the stack.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315852/upgrade-to-enterprise-library-6-0-giving-issues-with-enterpriselibrarycontainer